# Make Custom Actions open in current tab

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-actions

I have a few Custom Actions for a list in SharePoint 2013. Every time one is clicked, it opens in a new tab, which means that very quickly a lot of tabs can get spawned. Is there a way to force the Custom Action (e.g. an edit form) to open in the same tab? I am using SharePoint Designer 2013

I tried putting the following code (with the correct URL) into the `Navigate to URL` field, based on something I found online, but it doesn't work:

`javascript:(function() {var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(); location.href = “/URL-TO-FORM.aspx?ID=”+items[0].id;})()`

Comment: Did you verify the `target` property for your custom action link/button?

Comment: How do I do that? By the way, I am doing this through SharePoint Designer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a test custom action using SharePoint designer with below `Navigate to URL` option

```
javascript:(function() {var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(); window.location.href= "http://www.google.com";})()
```

It is opening in the same tab.

Comment: I guess maybe I just needed the `window` in there